# Simulating multiple android devices

Tags: android, simulation

I'm in the process of creating an Android application that allows a host device to take on one of many roles in which it gathers, shares, or processes information.  Given the nature of the application, it is necessary not only to test the roles independently, but also to simulate the interaction among components.  Does there exist a platform that allows for the simulation of multiple android devices in a network?

I've had trouble finding meaningful search results, as the majority of results seem to be geared toward testing multiple *types* of devices, but not so much simulating multiple, communicating devices concurrently.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761246/possible-to-safely-run-multiple-android-emulators-on-the-same-machine-and-commun), it is possible to run multiple instances of the Android Studio emulator which communicate through sockets, but this does not seem like a suitable strategy for simulating large numbers of devices.

Comment: Please quantify "large numbers of devices".

Comment: Whatever testing you do, if its multiple devices and doing end to end testing through a network the tests will be flaky..

Comment: @CommonsWare My advisor has requested that I find a platform that allows for the simulation of thousands of devices, but I would be happy to find something suitable for hundreds.

Comment: for an advisor thats not very good advise if I'm honest .. good luck spending your time tracking down false negative tests ..

Comment: @MarkKeen Um, do you not run scale tests ever?  Hitting a server with multiple devices concurrently is fairly standard in testing.  You don't do it for unit testing, you do it to make sure there's no issues with load.

Comment: @MarkKeen I'm not sure that I fully understand the problem.  Can you explain this better so that I'm better suited to explain to my advisor why this is infeasible?

Comment: @GabeSechan yes I do, but thats testing load on the server (and depends on your scale strategy, out or up) - this is to do with with individual devices end to end testing.. which in my experience produces false negatives and cannot be a reliable means of app testing .. https://testing.googleblog.com/2017/04/where-do-our-flaky-tests-come-from.html

Comment: @MarkKeen And by his description, " a host device to take on one of many roles in which it gathers, shares, or processes information" its basically a server

Comment: @GabeSechan well thats an assumption from quite vague information - shares locally/remotely? A question was asked, I've given my 2 cents based on my experience, and other information I've read - I'm just letting the OP know that for the shear scale on which they are preparing to do this that they may get swamped with false data on end to end tesitng - quite a big investment to not go according to plan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My advisor has requested that I find a platform that allows for the simulation of thousands of devices, but I would be happy to find something suitable for hundreds

If you have a budget in the tens of thousands of dollars, buy a bunch of Android devices and network them.

If you have a budget in the thousands of dollars, buy a bunch of computers and run a handful of emulators on each.

If you have a fair amount of experience in systems administration and Android development, you could look into renting a boatload of Amazon EC2 instances, perhaps with one headless Android emulator apiece. This limits the up-front expense but is not going to be trivial to manage.

The best solution, IMHO, is to ignore Android for the time being. Abstract your code such that the "many roles in which it gathers, shares, or processes information" are implemented in plain Java (or plain C/C++, if that's what you're working in). Then you can test that code on regular PC hardware, rather than be stuck with Android hardware or emulators and their intrinsic. Creating test cases for hundreds or thousands of interacting "devices" will be difficult, but the result should be able to be run on a single PC, albeit perhaps a beefy one. Then, perform smaller-scale interaction testing of the Android apps that use this code. Even this seems likely to be outside the scope of a single student project, but it's closer than the alternatives that I outlined above.